# transition delay that does not work when menu is closing

Tags: jquery, css, menu, transition, delay

I have a problem with my menu; when I click to open, the opening delay is applied but not to the closing and when I click quickly, the transition does not start from the beginning.

```
// menu container
.topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: white;
   max-height: 60px;
   transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out;
}
// menu on mobile devices
.topnav.responsive {
   position: relative;
   max-height: 380px;
}
```

As you can see I use max-width for the transition. However it's only work during opening, and not when i close it.

Here's the full code on https://jsfiddle.net/kyks_/nf46hqu9/2/ 
For those of you who will have the courage to read it.
Im a beginner, that's why my code will certainly seem horrible to you.

Thank you in advance to those who try to help me.